Yet another Lucky Bamboo top of stem is yellow, slightly different conditions then previous questions
This plant is currently in a vase of water, with six others in the same pot. They all have identical conditions, same water, same light, location... Etc.
They are 7 plants all in an opaque white vase, the water is changed every 3-4 weeks or so. I rotate the plants every so often so light is even.
The other one that I had like this, hollowed away and died. It stayed green to the leafy shoots, but yellowed further and further until they turned black.
Really would appreciate advice to save it from happening all the rest, I looked at the other questions that were similar. And I guess the only option is to cut it and putting my own wax seal on the end... I'd lose the leaves though and it's beginning of winter so I worry it will just die outright if I Cut it at the "node" right under the yellow part. :(


@jsotola Ok, so why does the yellow from the stub continue down half the stalk, turn the plant black, and kill it then. And why are my other 12 plants okay?
